# Pattern match results inconstsent

Tags: regex, perl

I'm matching pattern `/\*` against string, containing `/*`. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't and I don't understand why. Here's the code:

```
my @tokens = ( "//", "/\\*", "\\*/", "\"", "\\\"", "#if", "#ifdef", "#elif", "#else", "#endif" );
for( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @tokens; $i++ )
{
    print "Matching \'$tokens[$i]\' against \'$_\'\n";

    if( /$tokens[$i]/g )
    {
        print "Match: \'$&\', pos = ", pos(), "\n";
    }
}
```

Somehow string `"abc // /* */ " \" #if // "` matches all the patterns in `@tokens` but string `"abc /*  */ " \" #if // "` matches all but `/*`. What am I missing?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you need to escape the `/` so the regex would be `'\/\*'` or `"\\/\\*"`, just guessing.

Comment: I don't think `$_` is defined in a C-style for-loop? Or maybe you are using a value from earlier in the code?

Comment: Tip: Could have written: `my @tokens = ( qr{//}, qr{/\*}, qr{\*/}, qr{"}, ... );` It's a bit clearer.

Comment: Tip: `"\""` and `"\\\""` produce the strings `"` and `\"` which are equivalent when used as regular expressions.

Comment: Tip: Using `$&` affects the performance of regex matches throughout your program. Better to use `/($tokens[$i])`/ and `$1`

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, He said what value `$_` has underneath his code.

Answer (score 0):

`if (/.../g)` makes no sense<sup>[1]</sup>. For reasons I don't understand, people keep trying to use it. Most of the time, use of this buggy code doesn't result in any adverse effects. Unfortunately, it did for you.

```
if( /$tokens[$i]/g )
```

should be

```
if( /$tokens[$i]/ )
```

As for determining the location of the match,

- `$-[0]` will tell you where the match started.
- `$+[0]` will tell you where the length of the match.
- `$-[0] + $+[0]` will tell you where the match ended.

---

1. Advanced users might sometimes use `if (/.../gc)`, but it's not appropriate here.

Comment: I was explaining what the `/g` was doing, which your original message didn't do. I should have also added "... which is why you should remove it" but didn't. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: @shoover, Re "I was explaining what the /g was doing", You tried, but what you said made no sense

Comment: Added a missing bit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me rewrite your code in an easier-to-read way:

```
    my @tokens = ( '/', '/*', '*/', '"', '\"', '#if', '#ifdef', '#elif', '#else', '#endif' );
    my $test_string = 'abc /*  */ " \" #if //';
    foreach (split(/\s/,$test_string)) {
            for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @tokens; $i++ ) {
                  print "Matching  \'$tokens[$i]\' against \'$_\'\n";
                  if( /\Q$tokens[$i]\E/g )  {
                            print "Match: \'$&\', pos = ", pos(), "\n";
                  }
            }
            print "\n";
    }
```

You can use `quotemeta` or `(/\Q ... \E/)` combo like above whenever you use a regex stored in a variable. you won't have to escape so many characters.

go to Perldoc for more info: [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

I understand that you tried to count number of times your regex (in @tokens) matches against your test string, and that's why you used `/g` and function `pos()`. However, `/g` is the one causes problem for only the pattern `/*`. If you leave out the global modifier `g` like ikegami answer above, it should match it for you, but `pos()` won't work.

Comment: Re "I'm trying to understand the problem myself", `pos()` is where the next match starts...

Comment: I just tested it again. You're right, even `if (/\/\*/g) {` doesn't work properly with global modifier `g`. There's nothing about `g` modifier that prevents the pattern from matching. It's just strange.

Comment: On a match operator in scalar context, /g does two things: It causes pos() to be set on match, and it causes the match to start at pos().

Comment: Even if you don't use `pos()` at all,  it still doesn't match the pattern `/*` with `g` modifier while it would match everything else. it matches the pattern `*/` with `g` modifier.